# List all objects and columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, information-schema

I need to list down all object inside an object and related columns they are returning from source table.

For e.g.

Procedure `usp_UspTask` is calling 3 functions

1. `fnt_Task1`
2. `fnt_Task2`
3. `fnt_Task3`

These three functions are adjoining and returning select list to `usp_UspTask`.

Now I want that list of tables and columns which are using inside all above three functions.

Is there any query which can return this information? I know about information schema but need related information form there.

Comment: Possibly related question: [How to find the name of stored procedure, based on table name search, using sql server 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6924257/4519059) ;).

Comment: I think this tool could help you: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-dependency-tracker/ I have not tried the dependency tracker but I have tried other tools from red gate (sql search and ants profiler) and they always work well. Tip: there is a free trial. (No I don't work for red gate, I just like their tools :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008 you can use sp_depends which returns all objects that this object depends upon and all objects which depend upon this object:

```
EXEC SP_DEPENDS fnt_Task1
```

This returns two datasets:

1. Dataset which contains objects depended upon: object name, type
   (table/view), updated, selected, column
2. Dataset which contains objects depending upon this object: name and type

Note sp_depends is deprecated and for 2012 and later you should use:

- sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities and
- sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities